# Assign a row number of matching dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe

| Work | start Date | work date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20/01/2023 | 30/12/2023 |
| B | 17/12/2023 | 05/12/2023 |
| A | 20/01/2023 | 20/01/2023 |
| B | 17/12/2023 | 07/09/2023 |
| A | 20/01/2023 | 30/12/2023 |
| B | 17/12/2023 | 05/05/2023 |
| B | 17/12/2023 | 17/12/2023 |
| A | 20/01/2023 | 30/06/2023 |
| B | 17/12/2023 | 17/12/2023 |
| C | 08/08/2023 | 17/12/2023 |
| C | 08/08/2023 | 30/06/2023 |
| C | 08/08/2023 | 17/06/2023 |

now i need a output like ,if start Date and Work date match for the particular value create a row_number column and assign zero .a value above start date should have 1,2,3,4 etc.. and value below the starting date should have -1,-2,-3,..etc in the row_number

| Work | start Date | work date | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20/01/2023 | 30/12/2022 | -1 |
| B | 17/06/2023 | 05/12/2023 | 1 |
| A | 20/01/2023 | 20/01/2023 | 0 |
| B | 17/06/2023 | 07/09/2022 | -1 |
| A | 20/01/2023 | 30/12/2023 | 1 |
| B | 17/06/2023 | 05/05/2023 | -2 |
| B | 17/06/2023 | 17/12/2023 | 2 |
| A | 20/01/2023 | 30/06/2023 | 2 |
| B | 17/06/2023 | 17/06/2023 | 0 |
| C | 08/08/2023 | 17/12/2023 | 1 |
| C | 08/08/2023 | 30/06/2023 | -1 |
| C | 08/08/2023 | 17/06/2023 | 2 |

```
def add_values(group):
    match_index = group['Date'].eq(group['sop']).idxmax() # find the index of the matching date
    group['values'] = '' # create a new column to hold the values
    for i in range(len(group)):
        if i == match_index:
            group.loc[i, 'values'] = '0'
        elif i < match_index:
            group.loc[i, 'values'] = '-' + str(match_index - i)
        else:
            group.loc[i, 'values'] = '+' + str(i - match_index)
    return group

result = df.groupby('model').apply(add_values)
```

Comment: What is the logic behind setting `row_number` to 1,2,3,4.. or -1,-2,-3,....? I'm having a hard time seeing the pattern.

Comment: You should check your output. I think something is wrong. For A, 2023-06-30 should be 1 and not 2 so 2023-12-30 should be 2 not 1. Same for B, 2023-09-07 is after 2023-06-17 so it can't be negative. I'm right?

Comment: You have two rows with (B, 17/12/2023, 17/12/2023)? Should be 0 and 0? (rows 6 and 8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there no matching date for value C but it has start date ,then it is printing negative value for all ,i need positive value for value above start date and below start as negative value if there is no matching date as well.

You can use:

```
# Convert to DatetimeIndex if not already the case
df['start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start Date'], dayfirst=True)
df['work date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['work date'], dayfirst=True)

def row_num(df):
    days = df['work date'].sub(df['start Date']).dt.days
    same = days == 0
    before = days < 0
    after = days > 0
    days[before] = np.arange(-before.sum(), 0, 1)
    days[after] = np.arange(1, after.sum()+1, 1)
    return days

df['row_number'] = (df.sort_values('work date')
                      .groupby(['Work', 'start Date'], as_index=False)
                      .apply(row_num).droplevel(0))
```

Output:

```
>>> df.sort_values(['Work', 'row_number'])
   Work start Date  work date  row_number
0     A 2023-01-20 2022-12-30          -1
2     A 2023-01-20 2023-01-20           0
7     A 2023-01-20 2023-06-30           1
4     A 2023-01-20 2023-12-30           2
3     B 2023-06-17 2022-09-07          -2
5     B 2023-06-17 2023-05-05          -1
8     B 2023-06-17 2023-06-17           0
1     B 2023-06-17 2023-12-05           1
6     B 2023-06-17 2023-12-17           2
11    C 2023-08-08 2023-06-17          -2
10    C 2023-08-08 2023-06-30          -1
9     C 2023-08-08 2023-12-17           1
```

---

**Another solution with `rank`**

You can use `rank` if you prefer but you have to separate work dates before and after start date:

```
# Convert to DatetimeIndex if not already the case
df['start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start Date'], dayfirst=True)
df['work date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['work date'], dayfirst=True)

def row_num(x):
    before = x < 0
    after = x > 0
    return pd.concat([-x[before].rank(method='dense', ascending=False),
                      x[~before&~after],
                      x[after].rank(method='dense')]).astype(int)

df['row_number'] = (df.assign(days=df['work date'].sub(df['start Date']).dt.days)
                      .groupby(['Work', 'start Date'])['days'].transform(row_num))
```

Output:

```
>>> df.sort_values(['Work', 'row_number'])
   Work start Date  work date  row_number
0     A 2023-01-20 2022-12-30          -1
2     A 2023-01-20 2023-01-20           0
7     A 2023-01-20 2023-06-30           1
4     A 2023-01-20 2023-12-30           2
3     B 2023-06-17 2022-09-07          -2
5     B 2023-06-17 2023-05-05          -1
8     B 2023-06-17 2023-06-17           0
1     B 2023-06-17 2023-12-05           1
6     B 2023-06-17 2023-12-17           2
11    C 2023-08-08 2023-06-17          -2
10    C 2023-08-08 2023-06-30          -1
9     C 2023-08-08 2023-12-17           1
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks the code worked perfectly fine .but i have one more query if there no matching date for value C but it has start date ,then it is printing negative value for all ,i need positive value for value above start date and below start as negative value if there is no matching date as well.is it possible?

Comment: @workpyspark. OK. I will try to fix it.

Comment: Can you update your example? (please be careful of the output!)

Comment: Thanks,i updated output added a value C for the new query as reference

Comment: the output still seem off, are you sure the values are correct?

Comment: yes i updated it as per requirement ,the previous solution you provided working for all condition but there is no equal date it is taking negative value for date above start date .

Comment: @workpyspark. Is it possible to have two same rows? check your input dataframe? And the last row of C is -2 not 2.

Comment: Hi Thanks,the previous solution worked for my requirement ,i sorted out the duplicate row before creating the input dataframe mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same interpretation than @Corralien.

Here is my approach using [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

```
sd = pd.to_datetime(df['start Date'], dayfirst=True)
wd = pd.to_datetime(df['work date'], dayfirst=True)

m = sd==wd

df['row_number'] = (wd.groupby(df['Work'])
                      .transform(lambda g: (r:=g.rank(method='dense'))-r[m].squeeze())
                   )
```

Output:

```
  Work  start Date   work date  row_number
0    A  20/01/2023  30/12/2022        -1.0
1    B  17/06/2023  05/12/2023         2.0
2    A  20/01/2023  20/01/2023         0.0
3    B  17/06/2023  07/09/2023         1.0
4    A  20/01/2023  30/12/2023         2.0
5    B  17/06/2023  05/05/2023        -1.0
6    B  17/06/2023  17/12/2023         3.0
7    A  20/01/2023  30/06/2023         1.0
8    B  17/06/2023  17/06/2023         0.0
```

##### handling groups with missing equal dates:

```
sd = pd.to_datetime(df['start Date'], dayfirst=True)
wd = pd.to_datetime(df['work date'], dayfirst=True)

m = sd==wd

df['row_number'] = (wd.groupby(df['Work'])
                      .transform(lambda g: (r:=g.rank(method='dense'))
                                          -(1 if r[m].empty else r[m].iloc[0])
                                 )
                   )
```

Output:

```
   Work  start Date   work date  row_number
0     A  20/01/2023  30/12/2023         2.0
1     B  17/12/2023  05/12/2023        -1.0
2     A  20/01/2023  20/01/2023         0.0
3     B  17/12/2023  07/09/2023        -2.0
4     A  20/01/2023  30/12/2023         2.0
5     B  17/12/2023  05/05/2023        -3.0
6     B  17/12/2023  17/12/2023         0.0
7     A  20/01/2023  30/06/2023         1.0
8     B  17/12/2023  17/12/2023         0.0
9     C  08/08/2023  17/12/2023         2.0
10    C  08/08/2023  30/06/2023         1.0
11    C  08/08/2023  17/06/2023         0.0
```

Comment: See update (I considered ranking from 0 when there is no matching date, but this is tunable)

Comment: Thanks for the update but there should be  no zero when start date not equal to work date.just it should start with 1 and -1 depend of previous and next date .in output in row number 11 it has to be -1,row number -2  and row number 9 is 1